# Algorithm to determine if two points moving around circle are approaching or separating

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry, trigonometry

I'm looking for an algorithm to determine if the distance between 2 points (p1, p2), moving around a circle at know velocity is increasing or decreasing from the perspective of the smaller arc between them.

[image]

- I know the position of p1 & p2 in degrees/radians.
- I know the speed (piV, p2V) of both objects on a uniform scale.
- I know the absolute value of the short arc between p1 & p2 in degrees/radians (always a positive value). But, if it helps I can also know the short arc as a negative or positive value in the sense that it is negative from the perspective of p1 when p2 is behind (right) and positive if p2 is in front (left).
- Speed is positive when they are moving counter clockwise and negative if they are "retrograde" (moving clockwise).

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/, e.g. something like if arc from p2 to p1 is <180 and speedP2 > speedP1 then they are closing. Now write logic for other combinations.

Comment: I just amended the question for Rory. The short arc is always known as a positive or absolute value.

Comment: @andreas, I have made numerous attempts to solve it in C, but those algorithms are too complicated and convoluted with too many corner cases to post here and not really relevant. I am hoping there is a more elegant solution that someone with a better trig/geometry acumen can point me towards.

Comment: If you're looking for "trig/geometry acumen", you should ask over on https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You know whether P1 is ahead of or behind P2, and you know which one is moving faster. So there are four cases to consider, or you could just do it with XOR. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @beta for his comment and which prodded me in the right direction. I had missed the fact that I could use the direction (positive or negative) that p1 is from p2 and which was already known. There was therefore no need to convert the values into other coordinate systems.

The answer is quite simple:

```
SIGN((p2V - p1V) * Angle) = (+ if separating, - when closing or approaching)
```

I reduced this to the following C code:

```
return ((p2V - p1V) * angle) > 0 ? 1 : -1;
```

This works well if one is using a signed separating Angle that is positive if p2 is counter clockwise (left) from p1 and negative when p2 is clockwise (right) from p1.

Answer (score 2):

The real challenge of this question lies in dealing with the polar coordinate singularity at 180 degrees, so I will skip this and use vector math instead, which is slightly less efficient but much easier to understand. Hopefully someone else more adept with modular arithmetic can resolve this issue.

Converting the angular position to Cartesian:

`(X, Y) = R * (cos θ, sin θ)`

Assume the objects have Cartesian  coordinates `P1, P2`. Introduce the 2D cross-product:

`A ^ B = Ax By - Ay Bx`

This is positive if A is clockwise rotated with respect to Be, and vice versa.

Assume the objects have angular velocities `W1, W2`, where a positive sign means travelling anti-clockwise as is conventional for polar coordinates.

When object 2 is clockwise rotated w.r.t. object 1 (`P1 ^ P2 < 0`, as in your diagram):

- If `W1, W2 > 0` and `W2 > W1`
- or, if `W1, W2 < 0` and `-W1 > -W2`
- or if `W1 < 0` and `W2 > 0`

... the objects are travelling towards each other; and vice versa for the opposite situation, swapping object labels. Compiling this into a single condition:

`sign(W1 - W2) == sign(P1 ^ P2) != 0`

Btw, `P1 ^ P2 = R^2 sin(θ2 - θ1)` using a trig identity, so simply checking the sign of `sin(θ2 - θ1)` would work.

Edit: turns out reducing the condition down to a single sine term makes the modular logic much clearer, by considering the behaviour of the sine function  -

`sign(P1 ^ P2) = sign(180 - [θ2 - θ1] % 360)`

Comment: Sorry but Im not really seeing how to use what you've written. At the end of your answer you seem to suggest that this equation is the solution: sign(P1 ^ P2) = sign(180 - [θ2 - θ1] % 360) but I don't see how I would use that.

Comment: @CliffRibaudo that's just stating the two expressions are equivalent (at least I think), and you can use the second expression since it is more efficient. The actual condition to check is `sign(W1 - W2) == sign(P1 ^ P2) != 0` - replace the second term.

Comment: Actually... still confused. 1) what do you mean by ^, XOR? (I am working in c)  2) do you really mean SIGN where you write it or SIN?  3) Assuming you DO mean SIGN and not SIN what does SIGN(p1 ^ p2) mean? p1 and p2 are always 2 positive #s between 0 and 360 so not seeing how that solves anything.

Comment: @CliffRibaudo 1) the ^ is the 2D cross-product defined above, not XOR. 2) yes `sign` and `sin` are distinct functions. 3) `sign(P1 ^ P2)` is the sign of the cross-product of the *Cartesian* coordinates (not the polar angle) - I already defined the conversion from angle to Cartesian in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Move the reference system to `p1`. Now you have a static point `p1` and `p2` moving with velocity of `p2V - p1V` starting from position `p2-p1`. Now the question is: when will `p2` hit the origin?

Unfortunately, there are three cases here, depending on sign of `p2V - p1V`:

1. The speed is zero, points will never collide.
2. The speed is positive, meaning that `p2` will go round the circle and hit 360 degrees.
3. The speed is negative, meaning that `p2` will go straight to the origin and hit 0 degrees.

The only other gotcha is to calculate initial position of `p2 - p1` correctly. I'd recommend assuming that initial positions are between 0 and 359, and then adjusting `p2 - p1` correspondingly (if it's negative, add 360). Basically, calculating everything "modulo 360".